# Differences between two tables based on multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - Table 1 and Table 2. I am trying to get the records that exist in Table 1 but not in Table 2. In the example below, the record with Col1 value = P2 exists in Table1, but is missing in Table2, so I would like to retrieve that information.

**Table1**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
P1      FRA     DE      WE
P2      DEL     BG      US
P3      BER     CC      LP
```

**Table2**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
P1      FRA     DE      WE
P3      BER     CC      LP
P4      USA     DEL     LL
P5      GEL     PRO     JKE
```

I tried using below but its listing all the differences between the two tables. I'm only interested in knowing which records from Table1 do not exist in Table2 and not the other way around.

```
Select * from Table1
Except
Select * from Table2
```

So my expected result is

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
P2      DEL     BG      US
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Seems to work https://dbfiddle.uk/Py4hyvhc although probably wise to specify the column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
WHERE Table2.Col1 IS NULL
```

With the `LEFT JOIN` all the rows from the left table Table1 are joined with Table2 based on Col1 column, if there is no match in some rows the Table2 fields will be null, so with the `WHERE Table2.Col1 IS NULL` you return only the rows that do not have a matching row in Table2.

Comment: do I just need a join on Col1 or on all the columns?

Comment: if you only need to check for complete rows that are absent in table2, only col1 would be enough, if you also need  to check for differences like when in table 1 has "P1      FRA     DE      WE" and table2 has "P1      ENG     DE      ARG" then another query will be needed

Comment: Does it matter that this would not be correct if columns other than Col1 don't match?

Comment: @JuanC. thanks for your help. I used the query as you suggested and that worked. One additional questions: I'm inserting the result I get from this query into a third table with almost same column names. INSERT INTO TABLE3 SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col1
WHERE Table2.Col1 IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (.................)  I want to ensure finally that the records I am inserting in Table3 as a difference between table 1 and 2 dont already exist in Table 3. is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Sure, that should work, just be sure to complete the IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS, with something like "IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Table3
    WHERE Table3.Col1 = Table1.Col1
);" to check that the record does not exist in Table3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SELECT query with a subquery and NOT IN operator to achieve it.

Objective :- Select only those rows from Table1, where col1 is not present in list of col1 of Table2.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS T1 WHERE T1.Col1 NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT T2.Col1 FROM Table2 AS T2);
```

It will only check for unavailability of Table.Col1  in Table2.

To check if complete row is matching or not, we will have to concatenate all columns of a row as a single value.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS T1 WHERE CONCAT_WS( ',',ISNULL(T1.Col1,''),ISNULL(T1.Col2,''),ISNULL(T1.Col3,''),ISNULL(T1.Col4,'') NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT_WS( ',',ISNULL(T2.Col1,''),ISNULL(T2.Col2,''),ISNULL(T2.Col3,''),ISNULL(T2.Col4,'') FROM Table2 as T2)
```

Note - If any column has data type other than VARCHAR/VARCHAR2/NVARCHAR, Please CAST or COVERT those columns into any string data type in query.